# Strange stdout redirect behavior

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, ntfs

I noticed some strange behavior in redirecting stdout to files with special characters in 'the name'.

The ones I've found:

`echo.>f,test` produces a file called `f`, containing the text `,test`. Same with `.`, `;` and `<space>` (obviously the comma changes to whatever character).

`echo.>f.:test` produces a file of zero bytes called `F~000%HK`. The first character in the output file name corresponds to the redirect 'file name' between the redirect character and `.:` capitalized (I believe the `.` is ignored/removed for the same reason trying to create a file called `f....` just creates a file called `f`). I have no idea what the rest means, as changing the text after the 'file name' changes nothing. i.e. `echo.>f.:nope` still produces the empty file `F~000%HK`.

Another example of the same thing; `echo.>test.:test` produces a file of zero bytes called `TEST~4N5`.

In Batch the latter example produces the same result of empty files with the strange names, but the former example instead produces a file called `f` containing an empty line.

Any explanation / 'anomalies' to add?

Comment: The first one is simple, the comma is being treated as a terminator, ending the file name.  Use `echo.>"f,test"` instead.  I can't reproduce the other cases as written, but note that `file:test` is a valid pathname for the [alternate data stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) named `test` in the file named `file`.

Comment: On my system, the second case just generates "The system cannot find the path specified." which is as expected since I don't have an F drive.

Comment: The third case works as expected for me, i.e., it generates an empty file named `test.` with an alternate data stream.  What OS are you on?

Comment: Did you mean to say `echo.>f.:test` for the second case?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yep, just a typo.

Comment: OK, then, the second and third cases are the same, and are as-expected except that for some reason you're seeing the short, 8.3-compatible filename instead of the full filename.

Comment: With the first case - if it is being treated as a terminator, why does the file `f` contain the text `,test`? By the way, I know how to get around it, I just couldn't explain the behavior.

Comment: The command line, with the redirection clause removed, becomes `echo.,test`.  For [historical reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx#10074507) the dot is ignored, so the command echos `,test`.

Comment: Thanks Harry, makes sense in a bit of a silly way (silly in that I would expect cmd to handle it).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you would expect it to do?  I mean, do you think it should just discard the extra characters?

Comment: I wouldn't think that it should disregard the fact that the text comes after the redirect.

Comment: You can put the redirect anywhere in the line, it is often more convenient to put it at the beginning than at the end.  Putting it in the middle is probably pointless and arguably should be considered a syntax error, but I doubt it would be worth the effort involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`, ; = <space> <tab>` are standard delimiters so `echo.>f,test` is the same as `echo. ,test>f` . You can see what really happens in this case from a batch batch file with turned on `echo`.(just set `echo on` before the redirection). The redirection syntax could be tricky as it takes for a file only  the first argument and is with higher prio than the commands. You can change the result with `echo. >"f,test"`

As for the `echo.>test.:test` - you are redirecting to [Alternate data streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29) (are you with FAT32 or NTFS . FAT32 does not support ADS and results there may produce something different)? with `dir /r` (r switch is available from vista and above) or [streams.exe from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/bg-bg/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) you can check the state of ADS.To see the ADS content you can use more command:

`more<test.:test`

Here are the commands that I know that can read ADS: `FOR /F , FIND , FINDSTR ,MORE , CERTUTIL  ,CLIP ,EXPAND , SORT , MOFCOMP , FTP -S , CSCRIPT , WSCRIPT`

Notepad and Wordpad will delete the ADS if they open a file that have one.

Comment: If `echo.>f,test` is the same as `echo. f>test`, then why do I get a file called `f` containing the text `,test`? I am using NTFS. `/s` shows all subdirectories, is that what you meant?

Comment: @unclemeat yes you are right.Changed the answer. and the switch for datastreams is `/r`.Check the dir help.At the moment I'm with XP so my dir help is incomplete.

Comment: Did you mean `dir /R`?

Comment: @unclemeat - Yes yes.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that second comment before seeing that you already responded to my first. My bad.

Comment: In your updated answer I assume you mean "so `echo.>f,test` is the same as `echo. ,test>f `."? How does the fact that the character is a deliminator cause the line to be processed like that?

Comment: As the redirection (the `>`) operation is with higher priority than `echo` it is the first that checks the arguments.As it does not care about `,` unless it's in quotes it ignores it.So the echo takes what is left - in this case `,test` .It turns out that echo prints also the delimiters

Comment: Note that running the ADS example in a batch file with echo on, still shows the same line (with the addition of `1` for stdin) `H:\uprof\>echo.1>f.:test`. Thanks.

Comment: you can add the `set /p`command to your list: `set /p a=<f.:test` works.

Comment: notepad seems not to touch ADS. Only if I save the file with a different name, the ADS is not also copied. The original file keeps its ADS (as I expected).